# Loading multiple Ajax html in modal boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, bpopup

I'm using a jquery script by http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/ to open an html file in a modal box.

The HTML:

```
   <button id="my-button">Pop it Up</button>

    <div id="element_to_pop_up">

    <!-- Ajax Javascript that supposed to popup in modal-->
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#my-button').bind('click', function(e) {

            // Prevents the default action to be triggered. 
            e.preventDefault();

            // Triggering bPopup when click event is fired
            $('#element_to_pop_up').bPopup({
                contentContainer:'.content',
                loadUrl: 'test.html' //Uses jQuery.load()
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
    </div>
```

But I would like to extend this script so that I can open multiple ajax modals in a page, is there a way to bind this script together without duplicating this code over and over again for every ajax file to open?

Your help highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't that specific.

Is each one going to load from a different URL?

This may or may not be the answer you are looking for:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.my-button').bind('click', function(e) {//select all the buttons with a class selector

        var loadFile = $(this).data("file");

        // Prevents the default action to be triggered. 
        e.preventDefault();

        // Triggering bPopup when click event is fired
        $('#element_to_pop_up').bPopup({
            contentContainer:'.content',
            loadUrl: loadFile //Uses jQuery.load()
        });
    });
});
```

//your html:

```
<button data-file="test1.html" class="my-button">Load one modal</button>
<button data-file="test2.html" class="my-button">Load another modal</button>
<button data-file="test3.html" class="my-button">Load a third modal</button>
```

I'm assuming that your plugin bpopup can be used multiple times. I have't tested it.

BTW I don't know why your script block occurs within the div with id 'element_to_pop_up'. It doesn't need to be an it makes the code harder to read.

Comment: that actually works great. Thank you. I have one more question.  is it possible to go to the next html file within modal? For example, If test.html is open in the modal, and there is link inside that say go to test2.html, can it be done without closing the modal?  I have tried adding <button data-file="test2.html" class="my-button">Load another modal</button> in the modal, but it does trigger an event.

Comment: Oh and the reason why it uses #element_to_pop_up because thats the parent div that I wrap this javascript in. Without it, it doesn't work.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/justinwyllie/L2GYB/2/ - that would work I think except for issues with cross-domain policy. Just change the urls.